# Conectar VB6 a MSAccess

Tags: visual-basic-6, microsoft-access

Criei uma Base De Dados em MSAccess e criei um módulo de conexão. No entanto, quando o executo dá erro de conexão. Alguém tem um outro exemplo de como conectar VB6 ao MSAcess?

O código do meu módulo:

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Public T As Connection
Public c As Recordset

Private Sub conexao()
    Set T = creatobject("adodb.connection")
    Set c = creatobject("adodb.recordset")
    T.OpenRecordset " provider = microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;datasource = " + app.Path & "\alex.mdb"
End Sub

Private Sub desconexao()
    Set T = Nothing
    Set c = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Olá. Experimente imprimir `datasource = " + app.Path & "\alex.mdb"` numa `MsgBox` e verifique o caminho está correcto. A base de dados tem password?

Comment: ja fiz mas continua a dar erro,a Base de dados nao tem password.

Answer (score 1):

A sua função de conexão deveria ser:

```
Private Sub conexao()
    Set T = creatobject("adodb.connection")
    Set c = creatobject("adodb.recordset")
    connString = microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;datasource = " + app.Path & "\alex.mdb"
    T.Open connString // Abre a ligação para a base de dados
End Sub
```

Só após abrir a ligação com o `T.Open` é que vai poder realizar operações na BD.

Comment: Assim deu certo valeu pela dica,mas tenho um probleminha qual é codigo para  selecionar um campo na listbox e selecionarem se  todo os campos?

Comment: @user7752 Essa dúvida não está ligada com a actual pergunta. Sugeria-lhe que abrisse uma nova pergunta para a sua dúvida. Não se esqueça ainda de aceitar as respostas que o ajudaram de forma a ajudar futuras pessoas com dúvidas (consulte a [página Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)