# Validar campo em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-access

Em Moçambique existe um numero único  de identificação tributária (nuit), e esse número leva 9 digitos.
Como ficaria um aplicativo para validar o nuit atendendo as seguintes condições?

- Se forem mais(+)  ou menos(-)  que  nove(9)  digitos, diga ”nuit invalido.”
- Deve aceitar apenas números, se não forem números diga ”por favor digite apenas números”

Tenho aqui o algoritmo:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

v = validarnuit(TextBox1.Text)
MsgBox v

End Sub
Function validarnuit(nuit)
Dim cd As Double
Dim valido As String
valido = "Nuit Invalido"
If Len(nuit) = 9 Then
If IsNumeric(nuit) Then
If nuit <> 0 Then

cd = Mid(nuit, 8, 1) * 2
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 7, 1) * 3 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 6, 1) * 4 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 5, 1) * 5 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 4, 1) * 6 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 3, 1) * 7 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 2, 1) * 2 + _
cd = cd + Mid(nuit, 1, 1) * 3 + _
cd = 11 - (cd Mod 11)
If cd = 9 Then
valido = "good"
End If
End If
End If
End If
validarnuit = valido
End Function
```

Se o `cd`  fore igual a 11, é falso e não valida; se for igual a 10  também não valida; só valida se `cd`  for igual a 9. Image se a divisão for igual a 2, isto seria 11-2 = cd 9 e valida. Tentei usar este codigo em cima mas não dá 9. 
Alguem tem uma ideia eficaz de como fazer isto?

Comment: "mas usando MSAccess.vba", leva-me a perguntar, está a desenvolver a aplicação EM MSAccess ou está a desenvolver uma aplicação que *liga* a MSAccess?

Comment: estou a densevolver uma aplicacao em vba que liga o MSAccess.

Comment: Que bagunça..! Fiz minha edição e só depois vi que esta é uma [pergunta camaleão](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1115/ser%c3%a1-que-esta-%c3%a9-uma-pergunta-camale%c3%a3o), ô perca de tempo... @Omni, fique à vontade para reverter para a versão que deu origem à sua resposta (ou a mais parecida possível).

Comment: @brasofilo a resposta continua valida para todas as edições, a única diferença foi o numero de dígitos que o OP queria validar.

Answer (score 2):

(a seguinte resposta é relativa à esta [edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/20746/4))

Assumindo que está a receber os dados numa `TextBox` pode usar a função [`Len`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsw58z6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) para determinar o tamanho de uma `string`:

```
tamanhoEsperado = 9 ' Tamanho do número esperado 
tamanho = Len(TextBox.Value)
If (tamanho > tamanhoEsperado) Then
    ' Invalido
ElseIf (tamanho < tamanhoEsperado) Then
    ' Invalido
Else
    ' Válido
End If
```

Para poder determinar se são apenas digitos, o VBA tem a função [`IsNumeric`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/6cd3f6w1%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) que poderá usar da seguinte forma:

```
If(IsNumeric(TextBox.Value)) Then
     ' São apenas números, grave na base de dados
EndIf
```

Edit:

Para inserir o campo na base de dados:

```
' Abra a ligação
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "" 'Coloque aqui a sua connection string
conn.Open

' Crie a instrução INSERT INTO.
statement = "INSERT INTO nuit " & _
    "(nuit) " & _
    " VALUES (" & _
    "'" & txtnuit.Value & "', " & _
    ")"

' Execute a instrução.
conn.Execute statement, , adCmdText

' Feche a ligação.
conn.Close
```

Comment: Omni na verdade eu queria o modulo de conexao para a base de dados e como ficaria todo o projecto eu nao entendo muito de vba mas tenho um teste.se me puderes ajudar

Comment: @user7752 a sua pergunta não explica isso, na sua pergunta pede um sistema de validação em VBA e não o módulo de conexão à base de dados.

Comment: sim Omni mas na verdade eu quero o modulo de conexao com a base de dados.

Comment: @user7752 não é [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19140/conectar-vb6-a-msaccess) que quer? E se na realidade é isso que quer porque é que faz uma pergunta não relacionada com o que efectivamente pretende?

Comment: Private Sub Command2_Click()
 tamanho = Len(txtnuit.Value)
    If (tamanho > 8) Then
     MsgBox "nuit invalido", vbInformation, "informacao"
    ElseIf (tamanho < 8) Then
   MsgBox "nuit invalido ", vbInformation, "informacao"
    Else
       MsgBox "nuite valido", vbInformation, " informacao"
    End If
    If (IsNumeric(txtnuit.Value)) Then
 
   da debug aqui c.Open "select * from nuit", c, adOpenStatic, adlockoptmistic
c.AddNew
c("nuit") = "txtnuit"
     
       MsgBox "nuit registrado com sucesso", vbInformation, "informacao"
       c.Update
    End If
End Sub
fiz dese jeito mas da debug.

Comment: a variavel whit nao essta definida.

Comment: @user7752 corri o seu código e funciona como esperado (tirando a parte da base de dados). Um detalhe, para inserir dados tem de utilizar a operação `INSERT`

Comment: sim Omni mas a ideia é fazer com a base de dados  tambem tentei sem a parte da base de dados e funcionou, se puderes ajudar nesse sentido de funcionar com  a base de dados agradecia.abraços

Comment: @user7752 adicionei o código que permite inserir na base de dados

Comment: continua a darb debug ,no  conn.ConnectionString = "microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;datasource = " + app.Path & "\validar.mdb" object required

Comment: @user7752 veja [aqui](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) como construir a sua `connection string`

Comment: ainda nao deu certo desse lado.

Comment: Omni tens muito legal comigo.tanks pela dicas que me das.